# MySQL String Date Time Conversion

Tags: mysql, datetime-format

I need to convert a field from a source table when I append records to a target table. The source table field formatting looks like mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM and I need to convert it to yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.

For example, a record in my source table LastModified field contains 1/18/2019 01:26:04 PM. I need to convert it to 2019-01-18T13:26:04 in the target table.

Attempted to use both MySQL STR_TO_DATE() and DATE_FORMAT() functions with no success.

Attempted  variations of following:

```
INSERT INTO target ( identification, LastModified )
SELECT identification, Date_format(LastModified, "%y-%c-%dt%h:%i:%s") AS LastModified 
FROM source;
```

and

```
INSERT INTO target ( identification, LastModified )
SELECT identification, Str_to_date(LastModified, "%y-%c-%dt%h:%i:%s") AS LastModified 
FROM source;
```

Comment: Can you post your table definitions, can the target field receive a field of that type..

Comment: Why isn't the target table using a datetime data type?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using `STR_TO_DATE()` incorrectly. This should work:

```
INSERT INTO target ( identification, LastModified )
SELECT identification, Str_to_date(LastModified, "%c/%e/%Y %l:%i:%s %p") AS LastModified 
FROM source;
```

Note the format string: `"%c/%e/%Y %l:%i:%s %p"`

Comment: Using the suggestion, Str_to_date(LastModified, "%c/%e/%Y %l:%i:%s %p") does not seem to change the format from the original which looks like 1/22/2019 7:43:29 PM.

I do not know if I should be using STR_TO_DATE or DATE_FORMAT. Any time I try to format to get 2019-01-09T10:52:59 using either function the result is null. I’m testing the format using a simple select query.

Just in case it matters, the source field LastModified is a varchar(255) with contents that look like 1/22/2019 7:43:29 PM. The target field is defined as varchar(30).

Comment: What does this produce for you? ``SELECT Str_to_date('1/22/2019 7:43:29 PM', "%c/%e/%Y %l:%i:%s %p");`` For me it returns ``2019-01-22 19:43:29``.